# Why do the tag counts on profiles round up to the nearest thousand, and why aren't these decimalised below 10k?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, tag-score

I have a total score of 1,495 for the [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) tag, so my profile displays `1k`. I have a total score of 1,509 for the [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) tag, but my profile displays `2k`. This, at face value, makes it seem like I've got a much greater score in CSS than I do HTML, despite there only being a difference of 14 'points' and neither of them being anywhere near the 2,000 mark:

[image: CSS tag]

[image: HTML tag]

Firstly, why are tag scores above 1,000 rounded up like this? The tags are ordered by total score, so even if the CSS tag here did still say `1k` it would still appear above the HTML tag. Values below 1,000 aren't rounded up in the same way.

Secondly, although searching for "profile tags decimal" returned no results I imagine this has probably been asked before (so feel free to remove this part): Why aren't values under `10k` rounded down to the nearest 100 and displayed as a decimal value instead?

[image: Decimal Example]

Don't get me wrong though, I'm certainly not complaining that my profile now says `2k` for CSS, I'm just curious as to whether this has been discussed before.

Comment: On [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=round+up+is%3Aq) only a couple of questions/discussions/bugs exist on this topic...

Comment: Because that's the way it was programmed, of course.  With Jon Skeet being the usual trouble-maker, you can see the "k" leaking out of the box in his profile.

Comment: @HansPassant that's why I mentioned to only apply the decimalisation to tags with a score lower than 10k.